# Provide GROUP info details in R reactable nested / grouped table

Tags: r, rlang, reactable

I am creating a table in R using {reactable}.
The data I am using is grouped by Species
I would like that when I expand the group row, that I get details for the GROUP.
The examples in the {reactable} documentation only show how to provide details by ROW index.
How could I target the GROUP rather than the row?

Thanks for the help.

Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(
    group_info = case_when(
      
      Species == "setosa" ~ "Info about the setosa group", 
      Species == "versicolor" ~ "Info about the versicolor group", 
      Species == "virginica" ~ "Info about the virginica group"
      
    )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Species)



reactable(iris2, groupBy = "Species", details = colDef(
  name = "More",
  
  # i need to use the GROUP index, not the ROW index, however not sure how to implement this, would like the group_info to show on clicking/expanding the group
  
  details = JS("function(rowInfo) {  
    return 'Details for row: ' + rowInfo.index +
      '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(rowInfo.row, null, 2) + '</pre>'
  }"),
  html = TRUE,
  width = 60

))
```

Comment: Do you need `%>% 
  nest_by(Species)` instead of `group_by(Species)`

Comment: Like this? `reactable(iris, groupBy = "Species", details = colDef(html = TRUE,width = 60))`

Comment: I have figured out a workaround - will update, thanks for your comments